# Is complex $\mathbb{C}$ a Galois extension of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-extensions

I would like to ask the following:

> Is $\mathbb{C}$ the Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I considered the Galois extension in a finite field, thus I am stuck here.

I think $\mathbb{C}$ is not the finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, because it is not an algebraic extension. ($\pi$  is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, and we have the proposition "finite extension is algebraic extension").

Please help me.

Comment: Well, ${\Bbb R}$ is an infinite extension of $\Bbb Q$, since $\Bbb R$ is not denumerable but $\Bbb Q$ is.

Comment: What's your definition of Galois? If it is "finite, normal and separable", the answer is "no", if it is "normal and separable", the answer is "yes".

Comment: For the definition of Galois extension in Wikipedia see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension).

Comment: I know that Normality must be algebraic... but C is not algebraic extension of Q... Do i have the incorrect definition of normality?

Answer (score 2):

An extension doesn't need to be algebraic in order to be Galois (at least, not if it hasn't been explicitly required in the definition). There are different conventions regarding that, which give different answers.

Suppose a Galois extension is one that is both separable and normal. Then, every field extension over a field of characteristic zero (like the rationals) is separable, so you only need to check normality, which means every irreducible polynomial in $ \mathbf Q[X] $ which has a root in $ \mathbf C $ splits completely over $ \mathbf C $. This is trivially satisfied in this case because $ \mathbf C $ is algebraically closed - *every* polynomial in $ \mathbf Q[X] $ splits completely in $ \mathbf C[X] $. As such, the extension $ \mathbf C/\mathbf Q $ is Galois, by definition, even though it's not algebraic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's certainly possible, but I've seen far too many references to $ \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf Q) $ to use this convention.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Although some authors denote by $Gal(L/K)$ just the automorphism group, also for non-Galois extension. For example, $Gal(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})/\Bbb Q)=1$.

Comment: It seems interesting to relate this answer to the following one, where it is shown that $\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})} = \mathbb{Q}$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653358/the-galois-group-rm-gal-bbb-c-bbb-q-rm-aut-bbb-c-bbb-q