# The Galois group ${\rm Gal}(\Bbb C/\Bbb Q) ({\rm Aut}(\Bbb C/\Bbb Q)).$

Tags: galois-theory, automorphism-group

I solved at

For $f$ in ${\rm Gal}(\Bbb C/\Bbb Q),$

$F(i)$ is $i$ or $-i$

And for $a,b$ in $\Bbb Q$, $f(a+bi)=a+bf(i)$.

I have to classify $G(\Bbb C/\Bbb Q)$, but I find the automorphism $f$ is defined on $\Bbb Q[i]$, that is the coefficient $a,b$ of $a+bi$ is rational...

How can I extended for irrational?

Comment: I have to classify G(C/Q), but i find the automorphism f is defined on Q[i], that is the coefficient a,b of a+bi is rational... how can i extended for irrational?

Comment: You won't be able to. This group is a huge complicated mess, which depends on which version of the axiom of choice you work with. This is probably not what you want to do if this is part of a homework assignment.

Comment: I have to prove C/Q is galois extension. But i dont know what to do....

Comment: Finding the automorphism group is definitely not the way to prove that an extension is Galois. In this case the bad news is that it is not true because it is not even an algebraic extension.

Comment: Is the definition of galois extension K/F is fixed field E_G(K/F)=F? I probably your definition is when algebraic extension. I consider although it is not finite, or algebraic.

Comment: You should edit your whole question to explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you said in the comment, what you actually want to do is show that $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois in the sense that $\mathbb{C}^{\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})} = \mathbb{Q}$. In other words, you want to show that if $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, there is an automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\varphi(z)\neq z$. This most definitely does not require to classify all automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$.

As a first comment, this relies heavily on the axiom of choice: you can find models of ZF where the only non-trivial automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ is the conjugation. This being said, once we don't mind using transcendence bases, we can answer your question.

If $z$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, write $\mathbb{Q}\subset K\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is purely transcendental and $\mathbb{C}/K$ is algebraic. Then $\mathbb{C}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$ and $z$ is algebraic over $K$, so there is an automorphism $\phi\in \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/K)$ such that $\varphi(z)\neq z$.

If $z$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, then we can choose a transcendence basis $S$ of $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ with $z\in S$. Then there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ swapping $z$ with another element of $S$. This automorphism can be extended to $\mathbb{C}$ since it is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$.